# Can I test my Repository in Spring Boot without actually saving test data in the database?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a Spring Boot application with some REST endpoints and I have a MongoDB. I would like to create a test that runs every time the project is built. The test should simply take some mock data and put it into the database and use that mock data to test that the endpoints return the correct results. If it's possible, I don't want the mock data to actually go all the way to the database. I believe I've seen something before where Spring could simulate the database. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: According to an old song (and movie), Grease is the word. In your case, however, mocking is the word (as in to mock a service).
here's one place to start: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-series

Comment: You can use Test containers(https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/junit_5/) which is very good for integration testing. Which database are you using, I can post a example for that.

Comment: @Akbar I'm using MongoDB

Comment: @Ben Look at this example, it is using mongodb and test containers. https://rieckpil.de/mongodb-testcontainers-setup-for-datamongotest/

Comment: @Akbar Okay, I will try that. That looks exactly like what i was searching for. Thank you :)

Comment: I don't know how somehow I bypassed the word MongoDB. I deleted my answer. May be this other question can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970690/how-to-unit-test-a-spring-boot-mongorepository

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example  for testing JPA Queries with Spring Boot and @DataJpaTest

https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-data-jpa-test/

Comment: Okay, I've come across this however I'm using a MongoDB not SQL, so I'm not sure how to use @DataJpaTest with mongo, or if it's even possible.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but @DataJpaTest usable only in SQL database

Answer (score 0):

**If you wanna "unit" test your controller**
You can use @WebMvcTest and just mock your service calls from controller.
Find out here a pretty good getting started with @WebMvcTest https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-web-controller-test/

**If you really need to do integration tests**
You can use embedded mongoDb database and `@SpringBootTest` in combination with `@DataMongoTest` annotation (Find out [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-embedded-mongodb) how to do that.
`@SpringBootTest` will load your applicationContext and `@DataMongoTest` will autoconfigure all you need for seting up the embedded mongoDb database.

`de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo` provides embedded MongoDB for integration tests. So you need to add its dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you wanna prefill your database you can create a bean in a spring configuration class

```
@Bean
  public Boolean preFill(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) throws IOException {
     JSONParser parser = getJsonParser();
      List dbObjects = /* Init your objects to insert here */;

      for (Object dbObject : dbObjects) {
        Document document = new Document(parser.parseJson(JSON.serialize(dbObject)));
        mongoTemplate.insert(document, dbObject.getKey());
      }
    });
    return true;
  }
  
  private JSONParser getJsonParser() {
    JsonParserFactory factory= JsonParserFactory.getInstance();
    return factory.newJsonParser();
  }
```